# “he was wishing he knew” of “he was wishing he had know”?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Is the following sentence correct?

“Lockhart called to the crowd, and he set off back to the castle with Harry, who was **wishing he knew** a good vanishing spell, still clasped to his side.”

Shouldn’t it read:

“ … to the castle with Harry, who **was wishing he had known** a good vanishing spell…”

Comment: had know does not exist and you have not provided a sentence, only a sentence fragment.

Comment: Passing over the sheer insanity of the implication that *any* ELL learner might know more about "correct grammar" than JK Rowling, I'd sum it up by saying that although one could ***justify*** using Past Perfect there, native speakers rarely would, because it sounds stilted/ pernickety. But they *would* use Past Perfect if the exact context had syntactically *forced* an explicit distinction between Past and "Past within the Past". Such as *...who was wishing he had known the vanishing spell earlier, before Lockhart [had] spotted him in the crowd* (where my *second* PP would still be optional).

Comment: FumbleFingers, how does my question imply that I might know correct grammar better than Ms Rowling? (I’m not trying to mock you. Am I to understand that such direct questions are considered arrogant in Britain?)

Comment: @Zak I said very specifically that I would not second guess an author like that. That means: perhaps one should look for justification for something as it is. That is all.

Comment: Your alternate sentence means something quite different than the one that was actually written.So, no, she should not have phrased it differently than she had—unless she had meant to say something different than she did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Personally, I would not try to second guess J.K. Rowling**. She probably has the highest paid editors in the English language.

The sentence is fine. **As Harry was on his way to the castle, he "was wishing" some thing.**

But you really should post the full sentence.

As the boy **walked** down the street, **he was wishing** he had more friends.

A continuous action in the past at the time of a simple past action.

Comment: You might add some clarification about what the difference in tenses might mean

Comment: @eques I said it is a continuous action in the past. And I highlighted the other tense, which should be enough for many people.

Comment: By no means am I trying to second-guess J.K. Rowling. All I’m trying to do is to better understand a foreign language. 
In this instance I thought that an unreal condition (Harry didn’t know a good vanishing spell, just like the boy from your example who didn’t have enough friends) should be introduced with past perfect. 

For example: “I wish I had known that Gary was ill. I would have visited him” (the sentence implies that it is too late, that I didn’t visit him on time – an unreal condition).

Comment: @Lambie I meant the "knew" vs "had known" part, which you did *not* mention

Comment: @Zak Words matter. You did say: Shouldn't it read, etc. Then, you rewrote it. So, in effect, you are second guessing her. An action can be ongoing (past continuous) in the past when another action **occurred at a point in time** (simple past). And I point out that you did not give us the verb in the first part of the sentence, which I assume is  simple past.

Comment: The verb in the first part of the sentence doesn't particularly matter since the main verb "was walking" is the relevant part for understanding "knew" vs "had known"

Comment: @eques Actually, he has now posted the entire sentence.

Comment: I saw that, but that verb doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, it does: It could have been: Lockhart had called to the crowd, and he had set off back to the castle....

Comment: The main verb that is relevant is the "was wishing"; if the earlier part was past perfect for some reason, that would only suggest "had known" would be at the same time as "had called" whereas being in the simple past suggests that "had known" would be before "called"

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion to use the past perfect is not apt.

**To have known** something is to have *experienced* it, which would not apply in that sentence.

> She has known the harsh north wind on her cheek.

Once we know something in the sense of understanding it and committing it to memory, we *continue to know it* (unless we  forget all about it).

To say that Harry was **wishing he had known a vanishing spell** would be to say that he was wanting to have known such a spell at some time in the distant past, earlier in time than his setting off with Lockhart, when what he was actually wishing was to know such a spell at that moment.

Comment: But how can one otherwise introduce a past unreal condition?

Comment: @Zak: There is no way to mark the clause **(that) he knew** with a change of tense in order to have it be understood as past non-actual, not with the verb **to know** in its epistemological sense.  But it is understood from **was wishing** that it is past non-actual.

Comment: @Zak: But you could indeed say *Harry was wishing he **had taken** the time to learn a vanishing spell*.

Comment: This is very simple, if I say, was wishing + had known means some other thing occurred between some  past event (simple past or past continuous) and events prior to the past event. "Last night he was wishing for rain when the men had walked in before dinner."